# Git: how to checkout to commit created from another commit?

Tags: git, commit

I cloned a repo.

I checked out to commit `foo` of the past.

I made my changes and committed them -- call the new commit`bar` .

I checkout to master.

I now realize I want to go back to `bar`. I don't see it anywhere in the history (rightly so) -- is my commit completely lost?

Comment: All commits are created from previous commits (well, all except the first one, and any other you force to be a root commit). The trick is finding the raw hash ID of the commit. As Unapiedra said, look in the reflog for this hash ID. You may want to make a *name* (branch or tag name) that will give access to the commit, because reflog entries eventually expire, after which the commit itself will (eventually) be removed, unless there is a name by which to find it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `git reflog` to get which commits you had checked out in the past.
2. You can always manually checkout a commit using `git checkout foo` (foo would be the Hash of your commit).